# Convert hex number to binary and append 0 at the end in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to read a hex format file (32 bit) and convert each value to 33 bits by appending 0 to the LSB. For example `8000_0001` --> `1_0000_0002`.

I tried this program and other ways but couldn't add `0` at the end of converted binary format number.

```
%h2b = (
  0 => "0000",
  1 => "0001", 2 => "0010", 3 => "0011",
  4 => "0100", 5 => "0101", 6 => "0110",
  7 => "0111", 8 => "1000", 9 => "1001",
  a => "1010", b => "1011", c => "1100",
  d => "1101", e => "1110", f => "1111",
);

$hex = "4";
($binary = $hex) =~ s/(.)/$h2b{lc $1}/g;

open(INFILE1, "./sram1.hex") || die("$TESTLIST could not be found\n");
open(INFILE2, ">>sram2.hex") || die("$TESTLIST could not be found\n");
@testarray1  = <INFILE1>;
$test_count1 = @testarray1;

foreach $line (@testarray1) {
  $hex = $line;
  ($binary = $hex) =~ s/(.)/$h2b{lc $1}/g;
  print INFILE2 "$binary";
}

#close (INFILE2);

open(INFILE3, "./sram2.hex") || die("$TESTLIST could not be found\n");
open(INFILE4, ">>sram3.hex") || die("$TESTLIST could not be found\n");
@testarray2 = <INFILE3>;

foreach $line1 (@testarray2) {

  my $int = unpack("N", pack("B32", substr("0" x 32 . $line1, -32)));
  my $num = sprintf("%x", $int);
  print INFILE4 "$num\n";
  my $hexi = unpack('H4', $line1);
  print "$hexi\n";

  #}
}
```

Comment: You can't store 33 bits, the example is useless in indicating what you actually meant, and you posted more than a screenful when we're talking about something that can be done in one line of code and at most 5 lines to demonstrate. Please clean this up!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `8000_0001 --> 1_0000_0002`?

Comment: If those numbers are in hex then you have shifted the most-significant nibl left by four bits (`1` -> `10`) and the least-significant one by one bit (`1` -> `2`). Please be clearer. You also have a very badly laid-out Perl program there, and it has neither `use strict` nor `use warnings`. I have corrected the layout, but I can't improve it any more without changing the semantics of your code. *Please* publish something readable in future.

Comment: **Note** that you *must* `close` (or at least `flush`) an output file that you want to read from. Otherwise the data won't be completely written to the file, and you will lose data. Why did you comment out `close (INFILE2)`?

Comment: @ikegami yes its 8000_0001 --> 1_0000_0002 ..sorry for typo mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the left-shift operator, `<<`. But if you are running a 32-bit Perl then you have to divide the integer into two sixteen-bit chunks and shift them separately.

It isn't at all clear, but as far as I can tell your input file has a single hex value per line.

Using this input file as `sram1.hex`

```
11111111
abcdef01
23456789
BCDEF012
3456789A
Cdef0123
456789Ab
def01234
56789abc
ef012345
6789abcd
89abcdef
01234567
cdef0123
456789ab
```

This program seems to do what you ask.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in,  '<', 'sram1.hex' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'sram3.hex' or die $!;

while (my $line = <$in>) {
  chomp $line;
  my $val = hex($line);
  printf $out "%05X%04X\n", $val >> 15, ($val << 1) & 0xFFFF;
}
```

**output**

```
022222222
1579BDE02
0468ACF12
179BDE024
068ACF134
19BDE0246
08ACF1356
1BDE02468
0ACF13578
1DE02468A
0CF13579A
113579BDE
002468ACE
19BDE0246
08ACF1356
```

Comment: Thank you.. i am begineer in perl. I would take all above comments as feedback. Thanks once again :)